# Can a class template inherit from a full specialization of itself?

Tags: c++

I have a data type that has some information on it and may or may not store extra data.  Let's call it a Shard.  I've defined a base class that has some common functionality:

```
class ShardBase {
public:
  virtual void Frobnicate() = 0;
};
```

And I want to define a templatized sub-class of this that allows accessing that extra data:

```
template <typename T=void>
class Shard : public ShardBase {
public:
  virtual const T& value() const = 0;
};
```

*But* I want to handle the case where there's no extra data, so I can specialize Shard for `void`:

```
template <>
class Shard<void> : public ShardBase {};
```

And now `Shard<int>` has a `value()` method and `Shard<>` just has the base functionality.

What I'd *like* to do is have `Shard<T>` inherit from `Shard<void>` so that anywhere I don't need the type-specific information, I could just take a `const Shard<>&`.  I know I could just take a `const ShardBase&` in that case but I'd like to use `Shard<>` for symmetry with the API elsewhere.

If I do something like this:

```
template <typename T>
class Shard : public Shard<void> {
public:
  virtual const T& value() const = 0;
};

template <>
class Shard<void> : public ShardBase {};
```

Then all `Shard<T>` would be `Shard<>` as well and it would do what I want.  But naturally C++ gets grumpy about me doing this:

```
<source>:87:22: error: implicit instantiation of template 'Shard<>' within its own definition
   87 | class Shard : public Shard<void> {
```

It seems like what I want to do here is well defined in this instance, so is there a way to workaround this limitation or am I OoL?

Comment: You just need a forward declaration of the class so the definition can be put after the explicit specialization, e.g.: [godbolt](https://godbolt.org/z/To19dv4MT)

Comment: @Turtlefight post that as an answer!

Answer (score 5, accepted):

This is absolutely possible if the class definition & specializations are correctly ordered.

---

The problem in the example is that the main class definition comes before the explicit specialization:

```cpp
template <typename T>
// Shard<void> is not yet known to be an explicit specialization here
//                   vvvvvvvvvvv
class Shard : public Shard<void> { 
public:
  virtual const T& value() const = 0;
};

template <>
class Shard<void> : public ShardBase {};

// only here the compiler knows that Shard<void> is an explicit specialization
```

---

This can be fixed by forward-declaring the `Shard`-class, so that the explicit specialization `Shard<void>` can be placed before the definition of `Shard<T>`.

e.g.: [godbolt](https://godbolt.org/z/To19dv4MT)

```cpp
struct ShardBase {};


template <typename T>
class Shard;

template <>
class Shard<void> : public ShardBase {};

template <typename T>
class Shard : public Shard<void> {
public:
  virtual const T& value() const = 0;
};
```

Comment: In this particular example Shard<void> (AKA Shard<>) is the piece of the API that's common to all Shards and Shard<T> is then a Shard with some associated piece of data.  It's nice that all shards can be referred to as a Shard<> to write generic functions.  Do you know if there's any way I can convince C++ to let me elide the <> so I can just have Shard and Shard<T> as the two class names?

Comment: @gct fully eliding `<>` in all cases is not possible. `Shard` is a templated class and as such requires template parameters (even if all of them are defaulted). The only time you can elide them is some form of template argument deduction is possible ([CTAD](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/language/class_template_argument_deduction)) - but this does not help you because your class is abstract.